# Email confirmation system -- how to set submitted emails to recipient_list in signal

Tags: python, django, email, django-signals, django-email

I successfully manually sent an email to specific email address and activated the user but I cannot figure out how to:

1. Set submitted emails into `recipient_list` in my
   `post_save_activation_receiver` signal, since email field itself is defined in other model (if it is possible)?
2. Make this emails that I sent more secure, because gmail is treating
   them like potential fishing content.

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
# Create your models here.
from .utils import code_generator

USERNAME_REGEX = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*$'

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
                max_length=255, 
                validators=[
                    RegexValidator(
                        regex = USERNAME_REGEX,
                        message = 'Username must be Alpahnumeric or contain any of the following: ". @ + -" ',
                        code='invalid_username'
                    )],
                unique=True,
            )
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    zipcode   = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="92660")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True



    # @property
    # def is_staff(self):
    #     "Is the user a member of staff?"
    #     # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    #     return self.is_admin



class ActivationProfile(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    key     = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key = code_generator()
        super(ActivationProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def post_save_activation_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        #send email
        subject = 'Registration'
        message = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/{0}".format(instance.key)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = ['UserEmail']
        print(recipient_list)

        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=True)

post_save.connect(post_save_activation_receiver, sender=ActivationProfile)




class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)


def post_save_user_model_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
            ActivationProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        except:
            pass

post_save.connect(post_save_user_model_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db.models import Q

from .models import USERNAME_REGEX



User = get_user_model()


class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(label='Username / Email')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.cleaned_data.get("query")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user_qs_final = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__iexact=query)|
                Q(email__iexact=query)
            ).distinct()
        if not user_qs_final.exists() and user_qs_final.count() != 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid credentials -- user not exist")
        user_obj = user_qs_final.first()
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
                # log auth tries
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid credentials -- passowrd invalid")
        if not user_obj.is_active:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Inactive user. Please verify your email address.")
        self.cleaned_data["user_obj"] = user_obj
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.is_active = False
        # create a new user hash for activating email.

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user



class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, get_user_model, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

User = get_user_model()

from .forms import UserCreationForm, UserLoginForm
from .models import ActivationProfile


def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print(request.user.profile.city)
    return render(request, "base.html", {})



def register(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")
    return render(request, "accounts/register.html", {"form": form})


def login_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_obj = form.cleaned_data.get('user_obj')
        login(request, user_obj)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    return render(request, "accounts/login.html", {"form": form})


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")


def activate_user_view(request, code=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if code:
        act_profile_qs = ActivationProfile.objects.filter(key=code)
        if act_profile_qs.exists() and act_profile_qs.count() == 1:
            act_obj = act_profile_qs.first()
            if not act_obj.expired:
                user_obj = act_obj.user
                user_obj.is_active = True
                user_obj.save()
                act_obj.expired = True
                act_obj.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")
    # invalid code
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Replace `recipient_list = ['UserEmail']` with `recipient_list = [instance.user.email]`

2) Sending mails is complicated.
No, I am lying, sending mails is simple, making them arrive in the inbox and not the spam is complicated.
There are multiple factors why this could happen but I would check the following:

- Am I sending from the correct mail server - for example if you started a local mail server but the sender email is "foo@gmail.com" then to the receiving mail server this will look fishy as the sender is not gmail.com it is a bit more complicated but this is the short explanation
- Also check the content that you are sending - mails containing spammy words (body parts enlargement etc.) could be filtered.